# Show the second value based on the first one in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list on ng-repeat with names. I want to take this name and pass to url as parameter to take his subjects. What  i have done until now is that i can pass the name and get the subjects from another API. But the problem is that the last name replaces all the dropdowns with his values:

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <li ng-init="pass(person.name)">{{person.name}}</li>
    <li>
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in choices">{{value}}</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.person = {
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mark"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jakob"
        }
    ]
}

$scope.pass = function(name) {
    $scope.name = name;
    $http.get('url?name=' + $scope.name, {})
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.choices = response.data;
        },
        function(errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching choices');
        });

}
```

Note: There is a get method to pass the person.name at the end of the URL.

How can it be isolated to pass from HTML to controller.
Thanks

Comment: Pass the whole `person` object instead of `person.name` and then send `person.name` in the `pass` method. After the promise is successful, update `person.subject` from the response returned.

Comment: I updated the exact case of mine

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: I think you can use ng-change here

Answer (score 1):

Make your controller code like:

```
$scope.persons = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mark"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jakob"
    }
];


$scope.pass = function(person) {
    $scope.name = person.name;
    $http.get('url?name=' + $scope.name, {}).then(function(response) {
            person.choices = response.data;
        },
        function(errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching choices');
        });

}
```

And your html like:

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <li ng-init="pass(person)">{{person.name}}</li>
    <li><select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in person.choices">{{value}}</option>
    </select></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4019/

Comment: It does not work. Still shows the same everywhere. The name of last one in list.

Comment: You can check this sample fiddle demonstrating the above https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4018/

Comment: Thank you but this is not really good solution. I dont know how many names i have, i may have 1000. Can not make 1000 if else. i found a small solution with index but still facing problems on passing.

Comment: That doesn't depend on names. The example with timeout was to mimic the `$http.get` promise. If you have the url for http.get, I can create a fiddle with it demonstrating your real use-case

Comment: It is internal url. Can we simulate something on online distributors for testing http.get?

Comment: Use the above code in my answer above. I have edited it recently. It should work with `$http.get`, if it works with `$timeout`